# Angular Testing controller results in TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '$watch'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test my controller,
when I'm running the test I get:

> TypeError: Object # has no method '$watch'

In my controller I use $scope.$watch, how can I solve this issue?

**controllerSpecs.js**

```
describe('controllers', function(){
    var scope, ctrl,timeout;
    beforeEach(module('controllers'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        scope = {};
        timeout = {};
        ctrl = $controller('PublishersCtrl', {$scope:scope,APIService:APIService,$timeout:timeout});
    }));

    it('should have scope variable equals number', function() {
      expect(scope.number).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

**controller.js:**

```
controller('PublishersCtrl',['$scope','APIService','$timeout',  function($scope,APIService,$timeout) {
    $scope.number = 3;
     /* Make sure second click on order will revert the sorting */
    $scope.$watch('orderByField', function() {
        $scope.reverseSort = true;
    }); // initialize the watch

    APIService.get_publisher_list().then(function(data){
        $scope.render_table_and_filters(data);
    });
}
```

**Error:**

```
  TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '$watch'
       at new <anonymous> (C:/angular-client/app/js/controllers.js:24:12)
```

Comment: you are initializing `scope` to `{}`. So, `$scope` is `{}` and has not any angular method. Just remove the scope attribute in the beforeEach `$controller()` call.

Comment: @Utopik thanks, now i get different error, TypeError: Cannot set property 'number' of undefined i have in my controller $scope.number = 3, but now scope is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
describe('controllers', function(){
    var scope, ctrl, timeout;
    beforeEach(module('controllers'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new(); // this is what you missed out
        timeout = {};
        controller = $controller('PublishersCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            APIService: APIService,
            $timeout: timeout
        });
    }));

    it('should have scope variable equals number', function() {
      expect(scope.number).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

Is your apps module called `controllers`? What did you assign to your `ng-app`?

Comment: prefect it worked, but now i get an error, cause i'm calling another method from my original controller "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get_publisher_list'"

Comment: i updated the controller code, can you help? how can i mouck up the functions inside my controller

Comment: I think you should open another question for this as this has addressed the original one. Let's try not derail this answer, my be of help to someone else. Or we could move this to chat. @LiadLivnat

Comment: You need to test the service separately, I think. look at this http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.testing_services

Comment: please see other thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828179/angular-unit-test-controllers-mocking-service-inside-controller

Comment: For anyone that might hit the same issue as me, I had `scope = $rootScope.$new;` and my simpler tests worked. But as soon as I hit a $watch, i was getting this issue, it is important that your statement is `scope = $rootScope.$new();`