# Angular unit-test controllers - mocking service inside controller

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following situation:

**controller.js**

```
controller('PublishersCtrl',['$scope','APIService','$timeout', function($scope,APIService,$timeout) {

    APIService.get_publisher_list().then(function(data){

            });
 }));
```

**controllerSpec.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('controllers', function(){
    var scope, ctrl, timeout;
    beforeEach(module('controllers'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new(); // this is what you missed out
        timeout = {};
        controller = $controller('PublishersCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            APIService: APIService,
            $timeout: timeout
        });
    }));

    it('should have scope variable equals number', function() {
      expect(scope.number).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

**Error:**

```
 TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get_publisher_list'
```

I also tried something like this, and it didn't work:

```
describe('controllers', function(){
    var scope, ctrl, timeout,APIService;
    beforeEach(module('controllers'));

    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    var service = { 
        get_publisher_list: function () {
           return true;
        }
    };

    $provide.value('APIService', service);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
        timeout = {};
        controller = $controller('PublishersCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            APIService: APIService,
            $timeout: timeout
        }
        );
    }));

    it('should have scope variable equals number', function() {
      spyOn(service, 'APIService');
      scope.get_publisher_list();
      expect(scope.number).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

How can i solve this? any suggestions?

Comment: Your `controller.js` syntax is wrong

Comment: @dcodesmith yes i shorten it cause what really matters is the function call, ignore all the rest  APIService.get_publisher_list()

Comment: I refuse to help until you put that strict statement inside a function: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BcMF93NCQAAXKhW.jpg

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two ways (or more for sure).

Imagining this kind of service (doesn't matter if it is a factory):

```
app.service('foo', function() {
  this.fn = function() {
    return "Foo";
  };
});
```

With this controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, foo) {
  $scope.bar = foo.fn();
});
```

One way is just creating an object with the methods you will use and spy them:

```
foo = {
  fn: function() {}
};

spyOn(foo, 'fn').andReturn("Foo");
```

Then you pass that `foo` as a dep to the controller. No need to inject the service. That will work.

The other way is to mock the service and inject the mocked one:

```
beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {
  var foo = {
    fn: function() {}
  };
  
  spyOn(foo, 'fn').andReturn('Foo');
  $provide.value('foo', foo);
}));
```

When you inject then `foo` it will inject this one.

See it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WvUIrtqMDvy1nMtCYAfo?p=preview

#### Jasmine 2.0:

For those that struggle with making the answer work,

as of Jasmine 2.0 `andReturn()` became `and.returnValue()`

So for example in the 1st test from the plunker above:

```
describe('controller: MainCtrl', function() {
  var ctrl, foo, $scope;

  beforeEach(module('app'));
  
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    foo = {
      fn: function() {}
    };
    
    spyOn(foo, 'fn').and.returnValue("Foo"); // <----------- HERE
    
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    
    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: $scope , foo: foo });
  }));
  
  it('Should call foo fn', function() {
    expect($scope.bar).toBe('Foo');
  });

});
```

(Source: [Rvandersteen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4640433/rvandersteen))

Comment: What if I just wanted to make sure the fn function was called once?

Comment: @Jackie the spy has `.calls.count()` you can use to verify it is 1.